# Scala, passing values to a collection with Any

Tags: scala, collections, types, type-parameter

I'm building a framework for Actions in my web app. The basic idea is that it works offline, so I need a way to pass around actions that occur, which can then be rewound, merged, replayed and so on. ActionMeta is the class that enables this behaviour, and represents a single action, type S being the subject Type of an action. Here's the actual arguments that make it up.

```scala
case class ActionMeta[S](
  val timestamp: Instant,
  val syncKey: SyncKey,

  val action: Action[S],
  val subjectId: UUID,
  val subjectClientId: UUID,

  val originMeta: JsValue,
  val actionArgs: JsValue,
  val status: ActionStatus,
  val syncStatus: ActionSyncStatus,
  val subActions: List[(Option[Any], ActionMeta[Any])]
) {
}
```

This and its behaviours work to my specs for single actions and stacks of actions with the same subject, but now I need to address the final line, namely sub actions. The key issue is sub actions will more often than not involve a different subject. Actions themselves are inherited as objects from these traits:

```scala
trait Action[S] {
  val registryKey: String
  ActionRegistry.register(registryKey, this)

  def getSubjectIds(subject: S): (UUID, UUID)
  def pullOriginMeta(subject: S): JsValue

  def getSubjectRepresentation(id: UUID, clientId: UUID): S
  def saveSubjectRepresentation(subject: S): S
  def merge(args: JsValue, newArgs: JsValue): Option[JsValue]
  def deleteSubjectRepresentation(id: UUID, clientId: UUID): Boolean
}

trait CreationAction[S] extends Action[S] {
  def apply(actionArgs: JsValue = JsNull): (S, ActionMeta[S]) = {
    val (res, updatedActionArgs) = this.forwards(actionArgs)
    val (sid, scid) = this.getSubjectIds(res)
    val actionMeta = new ActionMeta[S](
      DateTime.now.toInstant, new SyncKey(), this, sid, scid,
      JsNull, updatedActionArgs, Done, LocalAction, this.runSubActions(actionArgs)
    )
    (res, actionMeta)
  }

  def forwards(args: JsValue): (S, JsValue)
  def backwards(subject: S, args: JsValue): JsValue

  def runSubActions(forwardArgs: JsValue): List[(Option[Any], ActionMeta[Any])] = {
    List()
  }
}
```

There is also the TransformAction[S] and DeletionAction[S] trait, which are similar but have different type signatures for `forwards`/`backwards`, and different logic for the `apply`.

```scala
object TestSideActionCreate extends {val registryKey = "actions:testSideCreate"}
  with TestSideActionBase with CreationAction[TestSide] {

  // omitted method bodies, not necessary to problem
  def forwards(args: JsValue): (TestSide, JsValue) = ???
  def backwards(subject: TestSide, args: JsValue): JsValue = ???
  def merge(args: JsValue, newArgs: JsValue): Option[JsValue] = ???      

  override def runSubActions(args: JsValue): List[(Option[Any], ActionMeta[Any])] = {
    List(
      TestActionCreate(
        Json.obj("id" -> UUID.randomUUID.toString)
      ).asInstanceOf[(Option[Any], ActionMeta[Any])]
    )
  }
}
```

Basically my problem is that `runSubActions` as it stands is clunky. This method does work, I'm able to access the resulting sub actions as I would expect with type intact, but still, this is where I'd be doing lots of my end implementation, my API, so I don't want to be forcing the compiler to let through a range of sub actions of different types by resorting to asInstanceOf if I can help it.

Is there a better way to express this in the Type system? I need to be able to accept anything in the `List[Option[Any], ActionMeta[Any]]`, as I don't wish to have my hands tied: as long as it implements `ActionMeta[S]` and has a corresponding `Action[S]`,  I can rely on it to behave predictably.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds almost like you want an `HList`. This is a heterogeneously typed list which can handle and preserve the various types of a list. Hence, you could have `Int :: Double :: Foo :: HNil` as your list and each individual entry in that list would still know it's type. The best, most power, and most complete example of this in Scala is Miles' Sabin [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless).

That said, Shapeless has it's trade offs and maybe a way to wrap your actions to hide or alleviate the need for `S` would be better in order:

```
 trait ActionOp[S]{
   def ids(that: S): (UUID, UUID)
 }

 trait Action{
   def getSubjectIds(that: S)(implicit ops: ActionOps[S]) = ops ids that
 }
```

Something where you're passing the type to a type class perhaps? Then you could rewrite your code to work on the "interface" of the type class and not worry about the actual type of `S`.

Comment: The wrapping sounds more in line with what I'd like to be doing. Think I'll have a longer think about how I'd do it though before proceeding.